# O método 'Value' do objeto 'Range' falhou

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, debug, value, userform

## Boa noite, estou com o seguinte erro:

> **O método 'Value' do objeto 'Range' falhou**

O código completo se encontra aqui: [Pelo GhostBin](https://ghostbin.com/paste/fwk9u)

[image: Erro]

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

''' Botão "CADASTRAR" código para inserir as informações fornecidas na planilha especificada.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MULTIPLICAR = 1

Sheets("CADASTRAMENTO_V").Activate

If Range("D5").Value = "NOME" Then
    Range("D5").ClearContents
End If

Range("D5").Select

''' Faça, se célula ativa não estiver vazia.
Do
    If Not (IsEmpty(ActiveCell)) Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True

ActiveCell.Value = Me.ComboBoxNOME.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.TextBoxSALDO.Value * MULTIPLICAR
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.TextBoxDEBITO.Value * MULTIPLICAR
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.TextBoxGARANTIA.Value * MULTIPLICAR
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = Me.TextBoxPLANO.Value * MULTIPLICAR
```

#### Quando acontece esse erro ele me manda para está linha:

> **ActiveCell.Value = Me.ComboBoxNOME.Value**

Alguém por favor pode me ajudar?

Comment: Aparentemente seu código não contem erros. Seria mais fácil identificar direto na sua planilha.

Comment: @AntonioSantos aqui está o projeto completo: https://drive.google.com/open?id=15hgrZS4DhhkexYtom-x7B_uLAD0uM4Fy

Espero que possa me ajudar amigo, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Infelizmente está funcionando comigo. Salva sem erros.

Comment: Crie um [mcve] com uma tabela com o valor que contém na célula. O que está em `ActiveCell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não sou muito fan de usar comandos da familia "Active". Por causa desse tipo de problema que pode ou não ocorrer.

```
Do
    If Not (IsEmpty(ActiveCell)) Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True
```

Voce pode subistituir por:

```
Range("D5").End(xldown).offset(1,0)
```

E assim usar diretamente pois este é um comando e não loop.

```
Range("D5").End(xldown).offset(1,0).Value = Me.ComboBoxNOME.Value
with Range("D5").End(xldown).offset(1,0)
.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.TextBoxSALDO.Value * MULTIPLICAR
.Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.TextBoxDEBITO.Value * MULTIPLICAR
.Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.TextBoxGARANTIA.Value * MULTIPLICAR
.Offset(0, 5).Value = Me.TextBoxPLANO.Value * MULTIPLICAR
end with
```

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

**[Respondendo suas perguntas]**

> "... e este código ele não irá sobrepor os dados ao eu abrir o
>   formulário por uma segunda vez por exemplo?"

*Não, este codigo que eu mencionei não deve sobrepor nada. Assim como o original ele procura pela ultima linha e depois preenche a linha de baixo com as informações resumindo sempre vai adc. uma nova linha de dados.*

> "...mas está dando erro neste código seu, algo me retorna falando que
>   preciso por o = (igual) O erro vai para está linha ->
>   Range("D5").End(xldown).offset(1,0) Poderia verificar para mim por
>   favor..."

*Estranho que tenha dado este erro poderia me compartilhar o arquivo com informações de exemplos para eu dar uma olhada e ajudar? Mas notei que tem um erro logico de minha parte neste codigo que te passei. No caso esta parte:*

```
Range("D5").End(xldown).offset(1,0).Value = Me.ComboBoxNOME.Value
with Range("D5").End(xldown).offset(1,0)
.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.TextBoxSALDO.Value * MULTIPLICAR
.Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.TextBoxDEBITO.Value * MULTIPLICAR
.Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.TextBoxGARANTIA.Value * MULTIPLICAR
.Offset(0, 5).Value = Me.TextBoxPLANO.Value * MULTIPLICAR
end with
```

*Melhor seria desta forma:*

```
with Range("D5").End(xldown).offset(1,0)
.Value = Me.ComboBoxNOME.Value
.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.TextBoxSALDO.Value * MULTIPLICAR
.Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.TextBoxDEBITO.Value * MULTIPLICAR
.Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.TextBoxGARANTIA.Value * MULTIPLICAR
.Offset(0, 5).Value = Me.TextBoxPLANO.Value * MULTIPLICAR
end with
```

*Note que eu tirei a linha de codigo:*

```
Range("D5").End(xldown).offset(1,0).Value = Me.ComboBoxNOME.Value
```

*E coloqui junto ao* **With**

```
with Range("D5").End(xldown).offset(1,0)
.Value = Me.ComboBoxNOME.Value 'ESTA LINHA
```

*Eu testei aqui como o exemplo abaixo e esta "ok"*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas está dando erro neste código seu, algo me retorna falando que preciso por o   =   (igual)

O erro vai para está linha -> Range("D5").End(xldown).offset(1,0)

Poderia verificar para mim por favor? e este código ele não irá sobrepor os dados ao eu abrir o formulário por uma segunda vez por exemplo? ele irá reconhecer que já tem algum registro feito e vai sempre para a linha debaixo?

Comment: Respondi sua pergunta no proprio post. Por favor de uma olhada.

Comment: Muito obrigado Hudson funcionou perfeitamente agora, agradeço a atenção!